# Let $A$ and $B$ be two $3 \times 3$ invertible matrices such that $A$ is an idempotent matrix. Then find $\det B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two  $3 \times 3$ invertible matrices such that $A$ is an idempotent matrix and $$\det(\mathrm{adj}(B))=\det (A)^{12}+\det(A-A^T)^{13}+\det (\mathrm{adj}(A)-I)^{14}.$$ Then find $\det B$.

Note:  Here $\det(A)$ denotes determinant of $A$
and $adj(A)$ denotes adjoint of $A$

**MY APPROACH:**
Since $A$ is idempotent so $A^2=A$ so $\det (A^2)=\det(A)$
$\implies$ $\det(A)=0$ or $1$

But it is given that invertible so $\det (A)=1$.

Now $A^2=A$ $\implies$ $A(A-I)=0$

**My doubt:** Can i conclude that either $A=0$ or $A=I$ $?$
But I've seen even when both matrices are not zero matrix multiplication can be zero.

Can anybody help me in this question

Comment: You can conclude $A=I$, since you are able to multiply $A^{-1}$ in $A^2=A$ by the assumption of invertibility of $A$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz So $\det (B)=1$ because other two $\det$ will be zero

Comment: That's an accurate deduction.

Comment: @mathophile You can conclude $\det(\operatorname{adj} B) = 1$ but not necessarily $\det(B) = 1$.  (e.g. $B = -I$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{adj}(B)B=\det(B)I$, so $\det(\mathrm{adj}(B))\det(B)=\det(B)^3$. Since $\det(\mathrm{adj}(B))=1$ we get $\det(B)=\det(B)^3$, so $\det(B)^2=1$. It follows that $\det(B)=\pm1$.